# Redshift Query BETWEEN returns nothing

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Here's the query that returns nothing:

```
select TOP 10 *
from table
WHERE 'date' BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-04'
ORDER BY "date";
```

Nothing is returned.

The following returns 10 rows:

```
select TOP 10 *
from table
WHERE 'date' = '2018-05-01'
```

BTW, the date column is TIMESTAMP.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure `'date' = '2018-05-01'` returns anything? That's comparing two different strings so it should be the same as saying `where false`. You're probably using the wrong quotes, double quotes are for identifiers (such as table and column names) like in your `order by "date"`, single quotes are for string literals. You should be saying `"date" between ...` and `"date" = ...`.

Comment: You likely need to typecast those dates in the `BETWEEN` statement.  `WHERE 'date' BETWEEN '2018-05-01'::timestamp AND '2018-05-04'::timestamp`

Comment: What is the format of your `date` column?

Comment: I've tried all of these proposed solutions and still no results
@John Rotenstein (awesome name btw) column is timestamp.

Comment: `'date'` is a string constant, not a column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` clause is always false, because in English it’s:

> where the string 'date' is between the string '2018-05-01' and the string '2018-05-04'

which is `false`.

Change `'date'` to `"date"`. You’ll then be comparing the `date` *column* (and the date literals will be automatically cast from text to date).

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me...

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow (foo TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO stackoverflow VALUES (GETDATE());

INSERT INTO stackoverflow VALUES ('2016-01-01 00:11:22'::timestamp);

INSERT INTO stackoverflow VALUES ('2018-01-01 01:02:03'::timestamp);

SELECT * FROM stackoverflow
WHERE foo BETWEEN '2017-02-02' AND '2018-05-04';
```

Data returned:

```
2018-01-01 01:02:03
```

**Tip:** Be careful when mixing dates and timestamps. A comparison like `WHERE date = '2018-05-01'` might only find timestamps that are exactly at midnight at the start of that day.